# Even after installing the new android app it is showing the older version's build error

Tags: android

My last published app has some issue while it got build.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'dagger.ObjectGraph dagger.ObjectGraph.plus(java.lang.Object[])' on a null object reference

There was some issue with the build apk, not the code.
Then again we generated the new apk and published it to play store. Now, the following things happen

1- The users who didn't install the last version can successfully install and run the app from the play store.

2- The user who has installed the buggy apk are getting the same error even on uninstalling the older version and reinstalling the new app from play store.

3- One of my testing phone showing the same issue as it has installed the last version but when I went for debugging(from the android studio) with the phone it worked like a charm.

Any suggestion what can I do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this options:
1. Try Uninstalling the app and then clear the RAM
2. Choose `Rebuild project` option under `Build` menu in Android Studio
3. If any of these will not work then, do `file->Invalidate caches and restart` option in Android Studio.

Comment: See, you didn't get this. My app is already on the play store and you can download it run it without any trouble. The people who have downloaded the older version first  are the ones who the facing this error. The earlier version has this problem. But it still showing on some phones even after installing the app and reinstalling the newer version.